# Remove directory from sonar analyzer

Tags: .net, static-analysis

How can I exclude a directory from SonarAnalyzer analysis, considering that I am only using the SonarAnalyzer.CSharp package, without SonarQube or SonarCloud?

I tried this, but the more specific rules overwrote it:

```
# Ignore paths
[**/Migrations/*.cs]
dotnet_diagnostic.severity = none
```